# Persistence with EJB3 doesn't work

Tags: database, ejb, ejb-3.0, flush, persist

I have a method to save a new object in an EJB bean. This method is called, without error, but nothing changes in the database. I can't understand why.

Here is the code:

```java
@Stateless(name = "Ar", mappedName = "ManagementBean")
public class ManagementBean implements IManagementBeanLocal, IManagementBeanRemote {
...
    @Override
    public int storeRawSms(String raw, String requestUid, String text, String service, boolean correctlyAnalysed, Date receivedTimestamp,
            boolean toBeAnalysed, String phoneNumber) {

        // Get phone number, create if it dosn't exist
        PhoneNumber pn = getOrCreatePhoneNumberPrivate(phoneNumber);

        // Create rawSMS
        RawSms rawSms = new RawSms(raw, requestUid, text, service, correctlyAnalysed, receivedTimestamp, toBeAnalysed, pn);

        // Store and return result
        em.persist(rawSms);
        int result =  rawSms.getId();

        em.flush();
        em.clear();

        return result;
    }

...
```

And the caller:

```java
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em; 
... 
int rawSmsIs = bean.storeRawSms(raw, requestUid, message, service, false, new Date(), true, sender);
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: have you checked the generated SQL? can you step through the method in a debugger?

Comment: add the code where you inject ManagementBean and where you invoke the method. Also where you inject the em

Comment: btw. the `flush` and `clear` methods are superfluous if you are using transaction-scoped `EntityManager`

Comment: For what it's worth, the `name` and `mappedName` attributes on the `@stateless` annotation are very likely unnecessary as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that your transaction never commited, so try changing transaction management:

```
@Stateless(name = "Ar", mappedName = "ManagementBean")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ManagementBean implements IManagementBeanLocal, IManagementBeanRemote {

      @Resource
      private UserTransaction utx;

      @Override
      public int storeRawSms(..) {

            try {
                  utx.begin();
                  ..
                  em.persist(rawSms);
                  int result =  rawSms.getId();
                  utx.commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                  //EXCEPTION HANDLING
                  utx.rollback();
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good experiment. If this works, then the problem is definitely that the container-managed transaction was not being committed. However, for a real fix, i think it would be better to make the container-managed transaction work properly, rather than to use a bean-managed transaction. It shouldn't be necessary to use a bean-managed transaction, and it will be harder to maintain.

Comment: I've seen this kind of (mis)behaviour many times, that's why I suggested trying "manual" transaction management. Agree, it would be better to lean on container-managed transactions for a long term.

Comment: Anyone who down-voted, please explain. This really *could* be the solution of the problem.

Comment: Hi, This was the solution to the problem. I tried the bean-managed transaction, with ctx.begin and ctx.commit, as propsed in the response. That was OK! Next, I tryed the solution with container-managed transactions, and using the REQUIRES-NEW as parameter, all is OK. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, glad to help. This is first time that I got accepted answer with -1 votes :D

Answer (score 0):

I see that you inject a reference to the EntityManager in the client (not sure why), but I don't see it in the session bean (maybe simply because you did not include the line in your message). Is it possible that you forgot to use the annotation @PersistenceContext in your stateless session bean?

Also, be careful: depending on the JPA implementation you are using and the generation strategy for the ids, you should call flush() **before** calling getId(). Indeed, if you let the DB generate your IDs, then you need a flush() to have this happen before the method returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the prposed solution worked!

I use the  container-managed transactions like this:

```
@Stateless(name = "Ar", mappedName = "ManagementBean")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ManagementBean implements IManagementBeanLocal, IManagementBeanRemote {
....
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int storeRawSms(String raw, String requestUid, String text, String service, boolean correctlyAnalysed, Date receivedTimestamp, boolean toBeAnalysed, String phoneNumber) {
....
```

Thanks again!